# Variance and Asymptotic normality of sample variance of normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, asymptotics, moment-generating-function

Let $X_1,X_2$,....,be a random sample from $N(q,w^2)$; $q,w$ are unknown. Let $S_n$ be the sample standard deviation.

i.e $S_n^2=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum(X_i-\bar{X})^2$

What is  $Var(S_n^2)$? and how to show that $S_n^2$ is asymptotically normal?

I tried to do Variance part using moment generating functions but expressions are getting extremely complicated.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  I've improved your formatting but you should check that I haven't introduced any errors.   If you want your posts to be readable you can use latex code in your questions, inserted between $ signs.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, you should add the "homework" tag.

Comment: Do you know the finite-sample distribution of $S_n^2$?  If so, you can start from there, and see what happens as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: I donot know distribution of $S_n^2$.

Comment: Also I need to show that $\sqrt(n)(S_n^2-w^2)->N(0,m)$ for some m function of w as n->$\infty$ in distribution.That is the meaning of asymptotic normality.

Comment: Is there any difference between the statement "$\sqrt{n}(S_n^2−w^2) \to N(0,m)$" which seems to say that the distribution of $\sqrt{n}(S_n^2−w^2)$ approaches a normal distribution as $n \to \infty$ and the statement "$S_n^2$ is asymptotically normal" which seems to say that the distribution of $S_n^2$ approaches a normal distribution as $n \to \infty$? Which one are you wanting to prove?

Answer (score 1):

I got it!
I came to know that $(n-1)S_n^2/w^2$ is distributed as $\chi^2_{n-1}$. From there I can calculate the variance.

Now $S_n^2/w^2$ is the sum of $n-1$ $\chi^2_1$ random variables divided by $(n-1)$.

From central limit theorem, $\sqrt{n-1}(S_n^2/w^2 - 1)\xrightarrow{D} N(0,2)$. Hence the asymptotic normality.

Comment: I've cleaned up the language. The general idea is ok, but the answer needs some polish.