# What is the exact definition of profile likelihood?

Tags: terminology, profile-likelihood

Does anyone here know the exact definition of Profile Likelihood? Or does it have one?

Comment: Refer to [S. A. Murphy and A. W. van der Vaart. On Profile Likelihood. *Journal of the American Statistical Association*. Vol. 95, No. 450 (Jun., 2000), pp. 449-465](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2669386) for details.

Answer (score 33):

I would suggest

[Sprott, D. A. (2000). *Statistical Inference in Science*. Springer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000PY3NU0). Chapter 4

Next, I am going to summarise the definition of the Profile or maximised likelihood.

Let $\theta$ be a vector parameter that can be decomposed as $\theta = (\delta,\xi)$, where $\delta$ is a vector parameter of interest and $\xi$ is a *nuisance* vector parameter. This is, you are interested only on some entries of the parameter $\theta$. Then, the **likelihood** function can be written as

$${\mathcal L}(\theta;y)={\mathcal L}(\delta,\xi;y)=f(y;\delta,\xi),$$

where $f$ is the sampling model. An example of this is the case where $f$ is a normal density, $y$ consist of $n$ independent observations, $\theta=(\mu,\sigma)$ and say that you are interested on $\sigma$ solely, then $\mu$ is a nuisance parameter.

The **profile likelihood** of the parameter of interest is defined as

$$L_p(\delta)=\sup_{\xi}{\mathcal L}(\delta,\xi;y).$$

Sometimes you are also interested on a normalised version of the profile likelihood which is obtained by dividing this expression by the likelihood evaluated at the maximum likelihood estimator.

$$R_p(\delta)=\dfrac{\sup_{\xi}{\mathcal L}(\delta,\xi;y)}{\sup_{(\delta,\xi)}{\mathcal L}(\delta,\xi;y)}.$$

You can find an example with the normal distribution [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27976/how-can-i-find-the-standard-deviation-of-the-sample-standard-deviation-from-a-no/27981#27981).

I hope this helps.

Comment: +1, very clearly explained; I notice you've been doing a lot of that